# How do I add resizing without IB

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, resize, iphone-5

Since starting with iPhone app development (last 9 months) I have only used IB. I have a project to work on already built by another developer that I need to optimise for iPhone screen.  No problem in IB, I know how to do that, in this project however the Nav bar is added using code only and is an image view.  Could someone advise me how I go about resizing/positioning the nav bar when IB isnt used?  Im trying to enhance this app for the iphone 5 screen.

```
#define BAR_FRAME CGRectMake(0,0,320.0f,43.0f)

 @implementation ICNavbarView
 @synthesize homeButton=__homeButton;
  @synthesize prevButton=__prevButton;
 @synthesize nextButton=__nextButton;
 @synthesize delegate=__delegate;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
 {
LogCmd();
self = [super initWithFrame:BAR_FRAME];
if (self) {
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.alpha = 0.9f;

    // Add Navigation bar background       // <<<<<< navigation bar from ui image
    UIImageView *bgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BgNavBarNew"]];
    [self addSubview:bgView];




    // Add back button
    __prevButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    __prevButton.frame = CGRectMake(30.0f, 6.0f, 29.0f, 31.0f);
    UIImage *prevButtonPressed = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BtnPrevPressed"];
    [__prevButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BtnPrev"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [__prevButton setImage:prevButtonPressed forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [__prevButton setImage:prevButtonPressed forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [__prevButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self addSubview:__prevButton];

    // Add next button
    __nextButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    __nextButton.frame = CGRectMake(262.0f, 6.0f, 29.0f, 31.0f);
    UIImage *nextButtonPressed = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BtnNextPressed"];
    [__nextButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BtnNext"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [__nextButton setImage:nextButtonPressed forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [__nextButton setImage:nextButtonPressed forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [__nextButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self addSubview:__nextButton];

    // Add home button
    __homeButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    __homeButton.frame = CGRectMake(145.0f, 6.0f, 31.0f, 30.0f);
    UIImage *homeButtonPressed = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BtnHomePressed"];
    [__homeButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BtnHome"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [__homeButton setImage:homeButtonPressed forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [__homeButton setImage:homeButtonPressed forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [__homeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self addSubview:__homeButton];
}
return self;
}

 - (id)init
{
return [self initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
 }

 #pragma mark - Button handlers

- (void)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
if (sender == __prevButton) {
    [self.delegate performSelector:@selector(navBarPrevButtonPressed)];
} else if (sender == __homeButton) {
    [self.delegate performSelector:@selector(navBarHomeButtonPressed)];
} else {
    [self.delegate performSelector:@selector(navBarNextButtonPressed)];
}
}

@end
```

So far I tried  `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;` like this

```
 // Add Navigation bar background
    UIImageView *bgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BgNavBarNew"]];
    [self addSubview:bgView];


    //resize

    bgView.autoresizingMask =  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

This seems to make no difference and the nav bar hasn't moved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used this before, but I used the setter function instead of using the property. I don't know if that would change anything or not, but try it this way:

```
    [bgView setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth)];
```

The parens are important, if you have multiple re-sizing options.

Comment: Marking this as correct as your comment about about Parent Views led me to the fix.  Thank you